# Insert text into textarea by link

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, insert, textarea

Here is my code:

```
<a href="">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>

<textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="replycontent" id="replycontent">Hello World</textarea>
```

I want to insert text at the end of the textarea by the click of a link. So if you click on the `Test 1` link, it will insert `Thank you` and so on. The solution will need to be compatible with all browsers (excluding IE6).

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcaqe/1/).

Comment: not sure about what you really want, anyway there is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Gcaqe/3/

Comment: @RafH That is exactly what I want, however, I noticed that it get replaced if I click both links. Is it possible that I can click both links and then both texts are added (rather than once being replaced)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gcaqe/10/

Answer (score 3):

set attrubute data-text fot link and try:

```
<a href="" data-text="Thank you">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="" data-text="Good luck">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>

<textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="replycontent" id="replycontent">Hello World</textarea>
```

javascript:

```
$("a[data-text]").click(function(){
  $("#replycontent").val($(this).attr("data-text"));
  return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqJVN/

**upd:**

For add(not replace text) in textarea:

```
$("a[data-text]").click(function(){
   var value = $("#replycontent").val();
   $("#replycontent").val(value+$(this).attr("data-text"));
   return false;
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vxeye/

upd by comment:
Paste text in **new line**:
http://jsfiddle.net/hkEmn/

Comment: Can you please update fiddle so that I can test its functionality?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it replaces the text in the textarea. I want to **add** the text at the end of the textarea content. How would that be possible?

Comment: Excellent, how compatible is this solution?

Comment: And is it possible to insert a new line in the textarea by a link?

Comment: Perfect, one problem though. I can't seem to make it work anywhere else beside jsfiddle. For instance, test it here: http://tinker.io/849a1 Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Found what the problem was, it appears that Wordpress admin area (where I execute this script) runs in **NoConflict Mode**, meaning that there is no `$`, but instead `jQuery`. Can you please update your question with this fiddle change and I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

use data attribute of HTML5 and click() event.. i added a class to `<a>` tag to be specific in selector.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="aClass" data-text="Thank You">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="#" class="aClass" data-text="Good Luck">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>
```

**JQUERY updated as comment**

```
jQuery('.aClass').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default behaviour of a tag 
  var val = jQuery('#replycontent').val(); //get prvious value
  jQuery('#replycontent').val(val + "\r\n" + jQuery(this).data('text')); //replace it.. ' ' so that there isspace beween the added text
});
```

**updated**

```
<a href="#" class="aClass">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="#" class="aClass" >Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>
```

**jquery**

```
jQuery('.aClass').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default behaviour of a tag 
   var val = jQuery('#replycontent').val(); //get prvious value
   if(jQuery(this).text() == 'Test 1'){
       jQuery('#replycontent').val(val + 'Thank You ');
   }else{
       jQuery('#replycontent').val(val + 'Good Luck ');
   }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcaqe/11/)

[fiddle in new line](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Gcaqe/14/)

[fiddle with both example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcaqe/13/)

Comment: Excellent, what about compatibility for this solution?

Comment: this is using jquery and html 5... jquery is cross browser compatiable.... where as HTML5 works in all latest browser.. if you just need to add the text .. use static text. wait will update my answer

Comment: Thank you, and is it possible to insert a new line in the textarea by a link?

Comment: Perfect, one problem though. I can't seem to make it work anywhere else beside jsfiddle. For instance, test it here: http://tinker.io/06b29 Do you know why it doesn't function? Must be something that I've missed.

Comment: that is because you haven't loaded jquery field in it... here is the working example  http://tinker.io/06b29/1.. you need to add jquery.js in settings > assets...

Comment: I found what the problem was, it appears that Wordpress admin area (where I execute this script) runs in **NoConflict Mode**, meaning that there is no `$`, but instead `jQuery`. Can you please update your question with this fiddle change and I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `span` tag to your specific word that you want to append:

```
<a href="">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "<span>Thank you</span>" to textarea<br/>
<a href="">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "<span>Good luck</span>" to textarea<br/>
```

Then you can use append():

```
$("a").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $("#replycontent").append($(this).next('span').text() + ' ');
})
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wAAPS/)**

---

or better you can use HTML5 data attribute for your anchor:

```
<a href="" data-text="Thank you">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="" data-text="Good luck">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>
```

then you can do:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var val = $('#replycontent').val();
     $('#replycontent').val(val + $(this).data('text') + ' ');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wAAPS/1/)**

---

**EDIT**

If you want to add new line whenever appending new value to your `textarea`, you just need to use `\n` along with your appended value:

```
$('#replycontent').val(val + '\n' + $(this).data('text'));
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wAAPS/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, and is it possible to insert a new line in the textarea by a link?

Comment: @GaryWoods Yes, you just need to add `\n` when you assign the value in `val()` function

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how I would do that, I couldnt make it work surprisingly.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, just one problem, I cannot seem to make it work on my site, it seems to only work at jsfiddle, for instance, see this: http://tinker.io/ee73f Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: I found what the problem was, it appears that Wordpress admin area (where I execute this script) runs in **NoConflict Mode**, meaning that there is no `$`, but instead `jQuery`. Can you please update your question with this fiddle change and I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @GaryWoods I've already updated my fiddle, sorry for late reply but nice to hear that you can fix another problem by yourself. Keep it up :)